# SSL handshake and gevent

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, asynchronous, gevent

In order to decrease latency we tried to use gevent in our program. 
However, using acyncio seemed to be tedious as we needed to rewrite a lot of code.

But using gevent yielded a lot of bizzare errors like `[SSL Handshake failed]`. After some digging we found out, that our Client hello packet was sent more than  ~30s after the successful TCP connection establishment. Setting `do_handshake_on_connect` option  to `True` only changed the name of the error.

We later found out, that the cause for the timeout was in some blocking operation(DB). Apparently, all the TCP connections were first established, then, when the first successful SSL handshake took place, first result was returned, and DB access would prevent the python from carrying out the rest SSL handshakes.

This happens, as I understand, because doing a SSL handshake(as every operation on socket) immediately "yields"(like in `asyncio`) to other io operations and it is unpredictable when it will be resumed

So, how do one correctly uses gevent with SSL ensuring the handshakes gets completed?

[image]

Comment: have you applied the gevent monkey patching? it replaces all io operations with yielding ones. That should also include DB operations

Comment: yes, we have. For now, i dunno why DB access is still sync, but profiling says it takes up 28% of time/ Ok, let it be some other CPU-bound task. If it prevents SSL from completing the handshake it is still very bad

Comment: If whatever doesn't yield still isn't cooperating after monkey patching and you can't change that, you'll have to put that code on a different thread. If you _do_ have control over it, you can try to locate the hot code and put some `gevent.sleep(0)` in it to see if that's the issue